# Android Studio 2.1 doesn't install in Windows 10 pro 64-bit system(build 10240)?

Tags: android, windows, testing, windows-10-desktop

[image]

When setup file that i downloaded from android developer site is run, it says "This app can't run on your pc to fin a version for your pc, check with the software publisher". My PC specs are as follows:
Processor: Intel Dual Core 3.0 Gz Memory: 4GB Display memory: 2099MB

Comment: Psychic debugging: Your CPU is 32 bit, but you downloaded the 64 bit android tools. [Related issue @ SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/518289/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-is-displayed-when-running-a-program)

Comment: Thank you but my system is 64-bit, i've checked it in setting in windows app.

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to a corrupt or incomplete install file. Try re-downloading.

Comment: Okay i'll download again and try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade your windows build.

You should try the official Microsoft tool to **perform build 10240 upgrade** :

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Click on "Upgrade Now" under "The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10".